# How to change the domain in cypress?

Tags: cypress

Suppose i have one test case in that i have visit two different url can it is possible in cypress!

1. google.com
2. youtube.com

describe('validate the functionlity of change the domain',()=>{

```
it('verify the functionlity of change domain',()=>{

    Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
        // returning false here prevents Cypress from
        // failing the test
        return false
    })

   cy.origin('http://www.webdriveruniversity.com',()=>{

    cy.visit('/Contact-Us/contactus.html')

   })
     
})
```

})

i have tried with this one it is working but my problem is that i want to use two different url in one test case

Answer (score 0):

If you need to visit two separate domains, such as the two you provided, you can do that by having separate `cy.origin()` calls.

```js
it('tests two separate domains', () => {
    cy.origin('https://www.google.com', () => {
      cy.visit('/');
      // code
    });
    cy.origin('https://www.youtube.com', () => {
      cy.visit('/');
      // code
    });
  });
```

If you run the above, with `cy.wait()` after the `cy.visit()` commands, you'll see that Google and Youtube are navigated to.

Comment: If you run this code, ***Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame***.

Comment: Hmm... what version of Cypress were you getting this on? I ran it with 12.0.2 and did not receive any errors.